# VBA Loop to select then copy a range of cells based on value in column B

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have references in column B and I want a macro to loop through column B and copy the cells range from A of the starting row to B of the last row for references that have the same first 4 digits.

i.e

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 13/01/23 | 0501765 |
| 14/01/23 | 0501766 |
| 13/01/23 | 0502023 |
| 15/01/23 | 0512301 |

So in this example the code would copy the range A1:B2 first, I would then tell it to paste it somewhere (I know how to do this), then it will continue the loop and copy the range A3:B3, and so on.

I just want to know what the syntax would be for something like this, can anybody help?

Thanks

I don’t know much about loops, here’s what I’ve come up with so far?

```
Dim WorkRng as Range

Set WorkRng = Range(“B:B”)

For i = 1 To WorkRng.Rows.Count
    If Left(WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).Value, 4) <> Left(WorkRng.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value, 4)
```

‘ I need some way to define the start row with the same reference and the last row with the same reference to select their ranges

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim FirstThisRow As Integer
    Dim FirstNextRow As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    Set rg = [c5].CurrentRegion
    On Error GoTo 1
    count = 0
    i = rg.Rows.count - 1

    For x = 1 To i
    FirstThisRow = Left(rg.Cells(x + 1, 2), 4)
    FirstNextRow = Left(rg.Cells(x + 2, 2), 4)

    If FirstThisRow = FirstNextRow Then
    count = count + 1
    Else
    1:
    Range(rg.Cells(x + 1, 1), rg.Cells(x + 1 - count, 2)).Copy
    Range("K4").Offset(x - count, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    count = 0

    End If
    Next x
    End Sub
```

Or, instead of looping through each one you could use autofilter to find each one instead?